# Arduino C++ - Error when trying to instantiate class which has non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, arduino, non-type

Here's the file where in which I try to instantiate the "Melodie" object:

```
#include <Melodie.h>

Melodie<5> m(8);

void setup()
{

}

void loop()
{

}
```

Here's the "Melodie.h" file:

```
#ifndef Melodie_H
#define Melodie_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "pitches.h"

template <int NB_NOTES>
class Melodie
{
public:
    Melodie(int pin)
    {
        // Some unimportant stuff
    }
    void addNote(int pitch, int duration)
    {
        // Some unimportant stuff
    }
    void play()
    {
        // Some unimportant stuff
    }

private:
    char notes_[NB_NOTES];
    char durations_[NB_NOTES];
    int  notePointer_;
    int  pin_;
};

#endif
```

I get the following error message:
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

Why? The same code works(minus arduino specific stuff) works in Visual Studio. I thought WinAVR supported C++?

Comment: That error messages comes with a file name, line number and position number. Please add them to your question and mark the relevant spot in your code.

Comment: +1 For those who are curious, the line with the error is `Melodie<5> m(8);`. Looking for an answer to this question as well.

Comment: I ended up not using templates at all, unfortunately :(

Answer (score -1):

I tried and compiled your code (GCC) without problem with two minor modifications.

1. Change `#include <Melodie.h>` to  `#include "Melodie.h"`
2. comment out the following

   ```
   //#include <Arduino.h>

   //#include "pitches.h"
   ```

since they are not used.

Comment: why do you think there is a difference between `#include <Melodie.h>` and `#include "Melodie.h"`?

Comment: The searching path is different for `<>` and `""`.

Comment: -1 GCC is not the compiler for the Arduino, this is a very misleading post.